# Submit after file finished browsing

Tags: jquery, html, file, post, upload

I want to do an auto file upload after the user has finished browsing, currently I have something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".bottom").css("opacity", "0.7");
    $("#uploadb").click(function () {
        $("#uploadfile").trigger("click");
        $("#uploadfilepost").submit();
    });
});
```

This submits **AS** the user browses the file...
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `change()` listener, instead of `click()`:

```
$("#uploadb").change(function () {
    $("#uploadfilepost").submit();
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/4TU5E/)